# XeLaTeX, otf fonts and dotless i

Tags: fonts, xetex, ubuntu

I am on an ubuntu machine with XeLaTeX and have been facing this annoying issue. On setting roman font to any of my otf files (Adobe Jenson Pro, Adobe Garamond Pro etc), the dotless i and j characters (`\i` and `\j`) default to ComputerModern.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setromanfont{Adobe Garamond Pro}

\begin{document}

{\Huge i \i \"{i}}
\end{document}
```

And this is the output:

[image]

The otf file does seem to have the dotless-i symbol but this keeps defaulting to CM. Some of my friends using a mac don't seem to be facing this problem though. Is this a non-mac specific issue?

Comment: What if you type the letter directly without using `\i`?

Comment: That works! (stupid of me not to have tried that)
But I don't understand why `\i` doesn't.

Comment: It works fine for me with a current miktex. Are you using a current tex live or do you use the outdated texlive of ubuntu? In the second case: check if fontspec loads `xunicode`, if not load xunicode *after* fontspec.

Comment: That works the way I want! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works fine for me with a current miktex. Are you using a current texlive or do you use the outdated texlive of ubuntu? In the second case: check if `fontspec` loads `xunicode`, if not load `xunicode` after `fontspec`.